# Kernel 4.4.0-109-generic fails to boot but 4.4.0-104-generic works fine

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, xubuntu

Xubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit, Nvidia GTX 960 with 384.111 drivers, Intel i5-6600k.

I recently updated my kernel and now Xubuntu fails to boot.

- I get a black screen when I select "Ubuntu" on GRUB.
- If I select "Advanced options for Ubuntu" then kernel 4.4.0-109-generic, it gets stuck at a screen saying "Press Ctrl+C to cancel all file system checks in progress" (pressing Ctrl+C does nothing). I am able to do the recovery mode boot for 4.4.0-109-generic.
- If, however, I select kernel 4.4.0-104-generic, the system boots fine!

Is this a regression? What should I do? Can I install an older kernel version and remove the broken one? Or is there a way to make the newer kernel work?

Comment: I would upgrade to kernel 4.4.0-110. IIRC 109 had bugs with Mesa.

Comment: I think you should report bug to [LaunchPad](http://launchpad.net) to inform developers about your problem with `sudo apport-bug linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic`.

Answer (score 2):

**Kernel 4.4.0-109-generic is bugged!**

The solution is don't use 4.4.0-109-generic. I upgraded to 4.13.0-26-generic and it worked fine. Upgrading to 4.4.0-110-generic may also work as WinEunuuchs2Unix suggested.

Comment: 4.13.0-26 has bugs too. I would jump to 4.14.13.